# How should I approach being able to retrieve images and description data in my React Native App offline?

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, mobile-development

I am building an app which will contain a large number of photos (200+) and about 100 descriptions of text. I need to be able to fetch and retrieve the photos and text and display them in my app however my client wants the app to be able to run offline without having to connect to the internet. I'm assuming I will have to embed the images and text data into my app itself. But I'm still new to this and was wondering what are my approaches to this and what kind of Backend I will need. The Images are in a form of png, and the text can be given in any form (pdf, docx, csv, it doesn't matter as I can always convert it).

Sorry if I am not being to specific, I'm still new and trying to figure out how to implement the data into my app.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can store all of your stuff in arrays - or if you’re accessing them by name, objects. Text should be strings. For images, I usually put the .pngs in a folder and in array use

```
[`require “(pathToImageFolder/imageName.png)”,require”(pathToImageFolder.png)”]
```

Comment: Should you store the information in my JSON file? Or should I just make the objects in my App.js file?

Comment: I think it's simpler and cleaner to store them in arrays in a separate file, export them from that file and import them into your App.js file.